# Java how to render a program with GUI

Tags: java, visual-studio, user-interface

I made a program that has `Buttons` and `TextFields` and is it possible to make and feel like real program. And render the program so that i can run in folders etc.

Comment: Is Java's swing library what you are looking for? There are a bunch of tutorials online. Looks like Eclipse has "windowbuilder" for building GUIs.

Comment: It doesn't look like you did any research... just Google "java GUI tutorial" and you'll find plenty.

Comment: Like a "real program"?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you can use [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) or [JavaFx](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm) to make GUI applications. Here is another link for [JavaFx](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/get_start_apps.htm).

If you want to export your GUI as an application that you can double click and run from your Desktop, you can export as a `runnable jar`. To do this in eclipse go to `File -> export -> Java -> Runnable Jar` and then choose the destination etc... Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file) for more information on different ways to make a java file executable.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't mean how to make them i meant how to render them like real program

Comment: @Dogux Do you mean that you want to make the Java GUI look like a native application instead of the Java look-and-feel? If so then you really need to clarify that in your question.

Comment: @Dogux If that's the case, then you want `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` (if you're using Swing.) If you're using JavaFX, then this isn't possible at present, since no native-like skins have been created that I'm aware of.

Comment: Yes, Thanks, and the that I asked was I can only run my GUI programs in eclipse i want to run them on the desktop or something

Comment: You can run swing and javafx applications from the Desktop if you export them as a `runnable jar` Then you can double click their icon on the desktop them to run them

Comment: How do I make my program runnable jar?

Comment: Is there another themes?